# class extending EventEmitter with type parameter

Tags: typescript, eventemitter, deno

I am working with deno and I have a class that extends this [EventEmitter](https://deno.land/x/eventemitter@1.2.1).

This class has some standard events but I want to be able to pass a type parameter to this class that contains some custom events.

The following is a minimal example of my code:

```js
interface StdEvents {
  ping: () => void;
  pong: () => void;
}

class MyClass<E extends EventsType = {}> extends EventEmitter<E & StdEvents> {
  constructor(socket: WebSocket) {
    super();
  }

  ping(): void {
    // do the ping
    this.emit("ping");
  }
}
```

But this gives me the error

> Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<(E & Events)["ping"]>'

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-XVmg9bT99U3LWum0WaGgC13zxRmE2hnqOnACw1AGltbrFRzPM3hSPxvWQH9C0vY9kDeKIf3idYUAaNsO2ULtwB7Yht3Vagly+J9wH3HgZ29ecyPOS41yPbD+xFDDiJnaCq3nZjmnVG87wfIgn0cF83w-L8tzA+FYPhX5LiggN2KJFkvDiJCGlRK0URRaBbj8ABCT0GjIGZkxmMgUEobARNYOIEh07A9IMshCjQMyvkLeti1LFtW1RFErJs+EUzIEI3O9OJNLISh8HwPw2N4DzVPdNBNh4LcrLbcl2xRW0eSwrc6MHLoRznBYlkIxjDzI08F3y5dKI9dc2Jw4qpxIw8opPU48po9i+1vHR70fLs+Nfd9oE-QrtCKP8JQA8AgNuED-HA8BII63hYPgxCLGQ7BUPSztx0w6ScLuMjRoag98NlcqKNXNBaoOujTqa5bWu0Fquq4vrxwGgThqEpZ5tEpUvgk+ApKvHhZOGeTFIUFEVJRHQFkaOpkCygYnrbFFYD0+ZFmWGZEgsLYdk8uKEqSzayAWRy0CgiJgzSGLUrQjCACUOBIFhB2wGwdHUn7XuBDa+TnDguDVISuZ5vmdAw9rRwYxrSLncq5bnaqHqY6SWhV89zqet6eu43iY2+kbrlucb-2IPVpuxYDQIWpaWtWhCFI2lDrR29C9rZqROY8J7FW-ShwG5+BeeuH7VceBWzrKtrdauy5jf4oazYtiadWtwC7dmh2AZ-N3ks9jK1F9jntAD5M+zyQ9PWF5cWpTwbBJuDSi827bS-Acv-dDqXI8-V7g-78Ppb19TwEMEhPXAAADb054w6g-Tnlq56dRVCEj5p8ELAd3T9yuDEDiXKAwsOI5+sjJ4WWB0gX+EN8dbfgQjff1XlNB7-AQ+K+Xk+LUg5bgeDwdIN9biP1YM-RUpBZSv13hrUqysvRqz+Eg-Wl05yvU4obD60ZU6t3Nv9VgaxAY-D+KDY8ZDiSsg7kpWGnlJ5+GpokbwvhbwIMXBkLIZF2F1k2AYBIYwJgtTiJ5LyKA8gNhcm8HgeQeB+AAEQAHUUDpEdPXd0g4WoAAKuF+jdPAFYSiYoongLAQoToNKsP4eATh8Ad7cN4XOOxdIhHjAmJpMREjvL6V8oZHQCBggtgxhYqxzCyIiPAN4rWPBxGqUkbpfxhpDKEAQGwamZjwnaEiXOaJr1ol+NssZUyQUEmMMSQjIgSN8a+GKQE-ygV4TBQxiiNJFjSzwEinEsxakNKGWwNAAAXv8dh4AAAMlkKYpK+H5dJXSskYz2PcSxxNYqljJu7LaqImZewwiqLguVE5zmdFwFAJBNiymdJQLg+JDrwBMCgfWN0MKk0Shg+OZ5hx62qtRUWaAMHBDCPOYFEJDTUSnAqai9cKqB2bqbQUXAiyWEWL+K2NAc65jziQr4EFCyBFCqEcI2QDxdJ4NgTUa0kj0J2WlbuhzZR4TImcz0lzrm3PvCCB5TyXnrneTxWOj0vm-OuuuAFQLiWgtCOCuZkKTKKhukLeF-UTZpyRWgFFaLqZiVYMDAlQRiXIFJU1cllLaFeBpdDZSTCNLaRmSUkyWSEgCu2RjaptSCYNNSU0hyQVNIYxypFUsVIqEsRiF+W4hlWBAngKZCynk4bw0RrKdUvgWoBENWEPpzD1TAkaNQJYeZcj5AaPAF1ZA9BoB0CgPwHqSAIDILwBROaNJNzmKNOYFTKmJIWYmdtOMlhzDae0sgfbuliLaalFE07mGDJGWM3wUztk+R9eOpZJNNmJTdbskuu0eSMuOT8siK9wA3KOTlR5Na4WvSVQKz5KDvmLiTjVDVkqQXlTBZcOVSqoWKvXLC9qQCEXqpMqiz8AL0WTWzrbbF7x86sHxeAQlwKSVkrVJSuCCErU5FrmWooVlyh7u9geoUR05ynvPbKS9vLb38q3YKvaJU9ZYKqmKt9QqZyoelSEWVPpf0KphacYDqrCE-TA2iyDOryH6uQ1mtDpqMNFAtWYHDJaCjFEIza1SzD7XJMdWUlpLqGM7tUh62UdSV2zLkIZAKfqWkBs8kGjJob9YRrzNGr4sb40VKTRsSwEik0okoFRp6maiXZpHcwgdnaZjdp7b2zp-a4nY1iyO0d67J0SJnRIlZVbr1gXkdKbtQX62NubdKQrLap2eVnQMuyC62FLumfpxp66goY1dcXHL9L91qHKtgVcJkNVap0IWQwVyz2cp5deoDcS1xvJM1COi2g9AGHubC5oOob0pc48g5cOtj1oOTntiIUrP0yu-fx9cf6hNPovHE6yomW4-QAI7bG2FBrOmLYP21xWgJDKGjU5HQ0GKl2HaVdz6-OQbVFhsAtG+NyboWaPXro7-BjGFlvhl0B4DbpwtuyibqdkVL732Kgu7xq7-7wC3aVbCkTn01WCXe-AT70mDRA0oXJiLCm-hKZU6YHDVltMoj8BJz8LZEgpBC9N7yALqYGt53TVIlgLItkrQmGtdbEYNtsBV+JnWTPdb2d3FR02coh2jgKJVUINVsD9Kerrpwv2GgfQdhOR22NUSVSjncp37yXHZeAaoW4SCYF6ucWAEQpC3llHmTg63CjVJtr7zlWPHE489NI-EIHBKvhPpbaDP2Zrwf+0hwP8B2VkLpJCaKxq8OFCKCa-nYOsMxBrG2M3FuBzMrnLbvkqpFxO+Ny7y7buSePtFT79cfv6JMcVnXaAQfJuh6-BH7i+gY+XIFAnuAl5w4LFT7P9Pe1sfaOzyQM5II88-QL9Hjn4lueV+r7Sek9fcOlqby3y4Au5KqYtB7VdRcnUzLXF2wHA38HdGwAbRYELHdAACtw40AEhkgpgJEXMX8rkABJfAN-OvHgXRDIXRdxWACRDAkNV6XwcLVDZASIWIVAlIILZhLAtAXAmJcZUghIIJR5HgdQZfKvK5PwVg3AvpFEaA2A7pVDPpA4cgxJEQv0epNoPMVgjg3wJRWvBkJRbLFYcEAwbLXEUsfglfByKXNA4QimNuRXfWYbSIOIeA+AJAnqPwbLFEWRIrRRJRYwxcdlTSUxbLCyPpXxSw3Gaw16WwhmZZRma0ckSoMAeIzCEgNbcAKQfAQRVbaQJARQYENUa4EwbQIsNAfATnH0K0cAWnfEZAMwlIJgEgaAfACocoqUEEKoxg8AWo+oioWIoJQTNMSwVweUTDDFG2Eoo0JEKYc0YY-UeERlNUTUcYYsIo0Ypg7kXQFNLYHqSrGAswUsZAFReAQwIsJIrEFA9A8o8o7ATYGwRRDyco2Ipo-EFsZADov0Mo84kAcAfAADU4TAfEVY8o+XIUZRX4kEUxRo-YeQckIAA)

Comment: It seems like there are type problems in the module you're using. Here's a TS Playground to demonstrate the equivalent of what's happening when you invoke the `emit` method and how it _should be_ typed: https://tsplay.dev/mL4nKm

Comment: Yes, your code works, but I have no idea how to get it to work in an EventEmitter like the one I use. I tried to add your implementation but it gives the same error AS before. Any ideal how to solle this?

Comment: There are plenty of other event pub/sub modules. Is there a specific reason you chose that one with the problematic types? You can also simply extend the native [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) class and dispatch your own [`CustomEvent`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent).

Comment: Here's an example of doing the latter: https://tsplay.dev/wE5XOw Does that meet your needs? If so, I can write it up as an answer. If not, can you explain why not?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped me very much. I have now set up an [EventEmitter](https://deno.land/x/evtemitter@1.0.0) with CustomEvents and EventTarget. So you can write it up as answer, because it really helped me and I like approach with the CustomEvents.

Comment: Note that it's [against network policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to edit questions in ways which change their meaning. The [last revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71224221/3) to your question changes it in a way that makes it no longer related to the original because you have completely replaced the code and the reference to the original module. You are, of course, always welcome to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have a different question.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Basically, the problem remains the same, I wanted to clarify, what the problem is and changed the question alongside that. Maybe I should add the new code after the original question?

Comment: If you're just wanting general help with your published TS custom event module, I'd be glad to participate in code review: I think it's interesting. Here's a link to a Discord server I created for that purpose: https://discord.gg/8JEvkzyT

Comment: I tried to join the server, but discord tells me, that the invitation is invalid.

Comment: In order to keep these comments on topic of the question, let's [continue in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242508/discussion-between-apollo79-and-jsejcksn).

Answer (score 2):

You can just extend the native [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) to make it a bit more convenient (and type-safe) to dispatch your own [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instances:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQ1gEBiCWA2CmAucA6Y8Bu8B2AXFuAzgLABQZI4AJjgPYC0s0e90A5trQE7zif3wAHgAcmAY2i56AQ2wBPMkOHdc4XHOG9I2ADwAFaV2kBbQuCG4cVMz2lVa2WHPCy5AbQC64ALzhb9x2dXTwAacAAleEIAV1hVX1cAPh8ycHAAChQs4UMTQmQDI1MASh9kyJi4gG4yRREVNQ1eADVpWGionQAVZN8utwBreDlaADNwLo8a8lIlBvVNCaaqAGFowlxaYwBRLDxupvNBS2xrcA2uZjYwgBF4XGk4H3Bo7AHOAHdsXtTwNY2trscLgdHcHnBkgAycAAbwWSCWmgAvtM6souKpRq8xLhoA5wGJbJYgXhwAdFhYrGYLldbvdHrBEulfvDkF0miFfjRwbAAPzIMEMzmkNLMST88AAeWMkh0-02Oz2uAAkthJGEAOTchkaxLC4ps5bywFK8nwOk85Iw35iBwbcwYVWSZ4wrIoMW4MLauAo348XDRLjYPjwD5-dYKkm4dLwsKYJ24UrSMzszSrCMm4Fmi0MxLTJG1Wb1DGNRbGxXAlZtWAAI2kYgGZqOJzONOwbGebeu4EFT18r3etC+PxFUF0bkwwMNafLUezPfpEI8YQwtGgVDzhcoNH4TBY7E4PD4DCU4kkMnkaPmhyjVdgtfrA0gXC2s9NXWbVMR8HTAIr+y7MIkhHNJtB0CclTZZdwFXddNxmOYS3hcM-yjABZaRhGeSJbS4KgdEAlDIyVeCrxLMRYGTMw32BLpDDYe5uk-U5qIzf9cAwrDfBw7h8OwScuDCfisC4RJkkpFjwCjOiuAY1RrVHbc6EYZgpAPbheDrbB6CIehbWMYxgV+SgAAFdPUnhfjsKgowAGWgDYcHgLgyQAaWYs4hhGcYP2hLsmV+NJWXAVzhTSNIxGrOsG2QW8osfZ9XzYud+lcjw9UC8BaGEXE7QlQoTHuZzCB0aT6PuNwNWsuyHJOZyNXStwACZl1+A0YLXKhYUy-1A2DGJNC4FBqqVezHP4rhmVHcLS3NTKIvihsXDMbZjiMHF9FyQzLC4EqytkiqqqoGzRtqpyuAaxI3AARmg7QMum8Lsty7BCDC8LimmNICxmNIqAcnJcDEAALNyPLMLyxgmcA-NwS52wCx7gtCzK3Tcb1YA8ZAppmtIB0+YMJLOVKPEqjGGvAXlwHRxc+WQfGh2wDx5vANk3DSsnaYpomzFeGhRmYH9KepjGJT5+ABf4qhmcetI2Y5rUua8HmQxE4XPBZ5AaZ5eXScVnkGplmbija5BYK6hSZttV7VEnUlfEJeBpGJJUYw5ahaaTXm3gJ5bwFadpOh6L7wtwYGHJQf7CEBkGo3SO3ExDn6uQB53Y6VMltnB-22g6EqeiZBPYvamtaFoBBZG6x7eqDc5okGyPU6B4G44Tz7fmTxTgA93dVNYDgNPALSdMIPStkMvBjO7szR4s+A-XgYxaCwGrxucsGVchnyYfOOGrkRmbkfehb72igZYqVO8HwbRLjBo-YSYembnrxV78q2ordtKpUZLkyqeCXivU6a8LqNRau9dq5sq4zRrv1euzkUAAOXvAVedVJos1jCzSKp9Hx+1WnDesIICrbWKt-Wi5VcD-0Xsg1B51Lo3Tut8Y+T0cqvzeplduo4fqdwoGAPhUA4AIjQEIEwoh4AEBIDMSgypjDokxC+Ywahga8CXlQWIvB+aCy6tIUuWBEC8PANAWRDQYSO2digpUYR764F-vcMIyFUw-msUicAowFHgA1MIpUEiNSolIJQVaoiED6JmMhPQVw9AODYOhTCLpfjCCuNOJxyVTQagSe2XUIdlDtiSb+YiWY0lRI1GEfy+Y-HW3tA8A68QQxhmsbYohESokxOEEyThZAsTYBxK-cAsBaDRKVL2WAGRMDIBhBjemPtGZIkgZ1aBBI7Tl3EX0tg8cMCR09vmQsVS5LDWOrQia6Q0lXGKb0-pUYhmcJ2fcPZJ1gRjTQUc7JbBTkrIuZs7ZFDG7RzTsDJ5JyrlfKjjHP5hSMmai6OHMwDkXDgGeQ6YEGp2mkGufgYFvz-ngthKYNgyANTKPvLQcAHxuCwCoBqGZ0xUXfJBXHMxLtgRPKKRCqFhizCyFoGHde8KE5IuRdSka9yzqHN+GCl571MBlAWa9JZKAVlrI2TyAgtAACqwhBpVkIPAdIxRijvRhA4MQCI4YdCRPqPx1KkFAKFSAplWK3mDI+aEoFTcQZ2vFR4yFMKYVcqUdAPCcKokIrwEiqlLqfnN3dacjUXroVmF9ZRe0PKlShs+dUmlvy6VEgsYy45GTdXTCAA)

`./event.ts`:

```ts
// deno-lint-ignore no-explicit-any
export type Fn<Params extends readonly any[] = readonly any[], Result = any> =
  (...params: Params) => Result;

export type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

export type TypedCustomEvent<Type extends string, Detail = unknown> =
  CustomEvent<Detail> & {type: Type};

export function createEvent <Type extends string, Detail>(
  type: Type,
  detail?: Detail,
  init?: Omit<CustomEventInit, 'detail'>,
): TypedCustomEvent<Type, Detail> {
  const evInit = {...init, detail};
  return new CustomEvent(type, evInit) as TypedCustomEvent<Type, Detail>;
}

export type CustomEventCallback<Type extends string = string, Detail = unknown> =
  Fn<[event: TypedCustomEvent<Type, Detail>], void>;

// deno-lint-ignore no-explicit-any
export type EventCallbackFromCustomEvent<T extends TypedCustomEvent<string, any>> =
  Fn<[event: T], void>;

export type CustomEventMap = Record<string, CustomEvent>;

export class CustomEventTarget<T extends CustomEventMap = Record<never, never>> extends EventTarget {
  // deno-lint-ignore ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  addEventListener <K extends keyof T & string>(
    type: K,
    callback: EventCallbackFromCustomEvent<T[K]>,
    options?: Parameters<EventTarget['addEventListener']>[2],
  ): void {
    return super.addEventListener(
      type,
      callback as Extract<Parameters<EventTarget['addEventListener']>[1], Fn>,
      options,
    );
  }

  dispatch <K extends keyof T & string>(
    type: K,
    ...[detail]: (
      unknown extends T[K]['detail'] ? [detail?: unknown]
      : T[K]['detail'] extends undefined ? [detail?: undefined]
      : T[K]['detail'] extends never ? []
      : [detail: T[K]['detail']]
    )
  ): void {
    const event = createEvent(type, detail) as unknown as Values<T>;
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  dispatchEvent <E extends Values<T>>(event: E): boolean {
    return super.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  // deno-lint-ignore ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  removeEventListener <K extends keyof T & string>(
    type: K,
    callback: EventCallbackFromCustomEvent<T[K]>,
    options?: Parameters<EventTarget['removeEventListener']>[2],
  ): void {
    return super.removeEventListener(
      type,
      callback as Extract<Parameters<EventTarget['removeEventListener']>[1], Fn>,
      options,
    );
  }
}
```

`./example.ts`:

```ts
import {createEvent, CustomEventTarget, type TypedCustomEvent} from './event.ts';

// Example:

type PingPongEventMap = {
  ping: TypedCustomEvent<'ping'>;
  pong: TypedCustomEvent<'pong', string>;
};

const target = new CustomEventTarget<PingPongEventMap>();

function logEventDetail (ev: {detail: unknown}): void {
  console.log(ev.detail);
}

target.addEventListener('ping', logEventDetail);
target.addEventListener('pong', logEventDetail);

target.dispatch('ping');
target.dispatch('pong', 'This is a pong event');

target.dispatch('ping', {msg: 'hello world'});
target.dispatchEvent(createEvent('pong', 'This is another pong event'));

target.addEventListener(
  'pong',
  ev => console.log(ev.detail.toUpperCase()),
  {once: true},
);

target.removeEventListener('pong', logEventDetail);

target.dispatch('pong', 'This is the third pong event');
target.dispatch('pong', 'This is the last pong event');

target.dispatchEvent(createEvent('ping'));
```

Comment: Oh man, I still get this error... If I extend the EventEmitter class and allow some CustomEvents, TypeScript tells me, that the type of the argument I gave to `emit` is not assignable to the type that it should be. I don't understand, why. Maybe because the event in the StdEvents could be overwritten by the CustomEvents?

Comment: This answer provides you with an _alternative_ to the other module you were having trouble with. It wouldn’t make sense to try to use them together.

Comment: I don't use the together. I have built [my own eventemitter](https://deno.land/x/evtemitter) with help of your solution. But now, when I try to extend it and allow custom events as in my question I get the error that `Argument of type [x] is not assignable to parameter of type 'unknown extends (E & StdEvents)["open"]["detail"] ? [detail?: (E & StdEvents)["open"]["detail"] | undefined] : (E & StdEvents)["open"]["detail"] extends undefined ? [detail?: ...] : (E & StdEvents)["open"]["detail"] extends never ? [] : [detail: ...]'`.

Comment: If I define the "open" event with `TypedCustomEvent<"open", undefined>` and don't pass any more parameters than the type of event to `emit()`, everything works, but if I define it as example as `TypedCustomEvent<"open", string>` I get this error